# Update records based on External ID

Tags: apex, externalid

When a new Applicant record is created with the same External ID as another Applicant, I'd like to update the original Applicant record with field values from the new record.

So far, I have the following code, which updates the original, but only with hard-coded values.  Is there a way to grab the values from the new Applicant record so that I can update the Original?

Thanks!

```
trigger FollowUp on Applicants__c (after insert, after update) {
    Set<String> newIds = new Set<String>(); // All new ID values
    for(Applicants__c record:Trigger.new)
        newIds.add(record.Formsite_Reference_Id__c);
    newIds.remove(null); // Ignore blank values
    Applicants__c[] others = [SELECT Id FROM Applicants__c WHERE Formsite_Reference_Id__c IN :newIds AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new];
    for(Applicants__c record:others) // Update Follow Up Value
        record.Follow_Up_Complete__c = true;
    update others;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modification to your code to achieve what you are looking for. I have not tested this, so you might have to fiddle with the code a bit to make it compile, but the overall idea should work.

**Notes**

I am not sure if you wanted to delete the newly created Applicants. If you don't you will end up with "duplicates". I added the code at the end for the deletion, but it is commented out.

Also, I made the trigger an after insert only. From your question, I was not able to assess what you would want to do if an existing Applicant's External ID was changed to a value that another Applicant already had as their external ID.

Good Luck!

Luis Luciani

```
trigger FollowUp on Applicants__c (after insert) 
{
    Map<String,Applicants__c> newIdsMap = new Map<String,Applicants__c>();
    //Build a map to quickly get a Applicant record based on the External Id
    for(Applicants__c record:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(record.Formsite_Reference_Id__c != null)
            newIdsMap.put(record.Formsite_Reference_Id__c, record);
    }
    //Query for all applicants that are already in the system with the same External ids
    Applicants__c[] others = [SELECT Id, Formsite_Reference_Id__c FROM Applicants__c 
                                WHERE Formsite_Reference_Id__c IN :newIdsMap.keyset() AND 
                                Id NOT IN :Trigger.newMap.keyset()];

    List<Applicants__c> applicantsToUpdate = new List<Applicants__c>();
    List<Id> newApplicantsThatAlreadyExisted = new List<Id>();

    //Loop through all the existing applicants and copy the data from the new applicants into them
    for(Applicants__c record : others)
    {
        Applicant__c fromTriggerNew = newIdsMap.get(record.Formsite_Reference_Id__c);
        Applicant__c forUpdate = fromTriggerNew.clone(false,false,false,false);
        forUpdate.Id = record.Id;
        applicantsToUpdate.add(forUpdate);
        newApplicantsThatAlreadyExisted.add(fromTriggerNew.Id);
    }

    //Update all the existing applicants with the new data
    update applicantsToUpdate;

    //May want to do this, not sure.
    //delete newApplicantsThatAlreadyExisted;
}
```